# How do you indent output in Jade?

Tags: pug

I wanted to indent an actual rendered line of html. Does anybody know how to do this? It seems to overlook whitespace.

I tried including:

```
app.get('/blog' , function(req,res){
res.render('blog' , {pretty:true});
});
```

But it didn't fix the issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.render`'s second argument passes a javascript object into the Jade view. Literally, you are passing a variable called `pretty` into the view, which has the value of `true`. It doesn't affect page formatting.

If you want to indent html output, you can either use `&nbsp;`, or the `pre` html tag, which preserves spaces and line breaks (though the font displayed will be fixed-width).

Example for `&nbsp;`

```
p
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is an indented paragraph.
p
    This is not indented.
```

Example for `<pre>`

```
pre.
        This is an indented paragraph.
    This is not indented.
```

---

Edit:

Alternatively, you can also indent the first line in an element with CSS.

```
p {
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just wondering, why is the pre tag giving the first line a gray background? If I pipe down to a second line is has a white background.

Comment: Do you mean the way I formatted the post? :o I had to play around with it to display correctly, just make sure there's at least 4 spaces at the beginning of the line to appear as gray, and there is a line break  above, separating regular text.